# How to get an advanced Combobox to have a normal dropdown?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I thought I had a working subroutine to populate the combobox dropdown with the top 4 search results in my two arrays, but now it sometimes gives four unrelated results when I first click on it; but then when the subroutine runs, it gives this weird incrementing thing as its dropdown.
[image: Picture Of Weird dropdown]
Here's the subroutine that's running:

```
Sub ComboFill()
ComboBox1.Clear
If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim Ships As Variant
    Dim People As Variant
    People = Filter(Module1.FullPeopleArray, ComboBox1.Value, True, vbTextCompare)
    Ships = Filter(Module1.ShipsColumnHeads, ComboBox1.Value, True, vbTextCompare)
    If UBound(People) > 0 And UBound(People) <= 3 Then
        For Each ComboLine In People
            ComboBox1.AddItem ComboLine
        Next ComboLine
    ElseIf UBound(People) > 3 Then
        For ComboLine = 0 To 3
            ComboBox1.AddItem People(ComboLine)
        Next ComboLine
    End If
    If ComboBox1.ListCount < 3 Then
        If UBound(Ships) > 0 And UBound(Ships) <= 3 - ComboBox1.ListCount Then
            For Each ComboLine In Ships
                ComboBox1.AddItem ComboLine
            Next ComboLine
        ElseIf UBound(People) > 3 - ComboBox1.ListCount Then
            For ComboLine = 0 To 3 - ComboBox1.ListCount
                ComboBox1.AddItem People(ComboLine)
            Next ComboLine
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I probably have no idea what I'm doing with some of these lines, so I might be going about it the wrong way entirely.

Comment: I feel you might be going about this slightly askew.  How about showing the Filter function since it is assigning to your variants array. Are you making this assignment right People = Array(Filter(Module1.FullPeopleArray), Combo1.Value, True, vbTextCompare)?  Hard to tell without you providing Filter.  In addition your use of ComboLine what is it in relation to an Array?  Arrays don't have ComboLines they have indexes, is

Comment: Can you provide the Filter function?  FullPeopleArray and ShipsColumnHeads? Is ComboLine declared as a Variant somewhere? You can use it as For Each in this manner but then you change it up and use it as an index later, not sure you want to do that and implement a true integer index here 1) Is your Array loaded properly into People and Ships? 2) Will have to look at your list logic based on array size . .

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code Yes, I checked the arrays, and they all look good. I don't have a filter function, just what is built into Excel VBA. The ComboLine's use in the for loop is it's declaration, so it should terminate after the for loop it's used in.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code At the moment, the Ships array is only 3 items long, and the people array is about 22 before filter, and 3-4 after. But the array's I'm bringing in from the other module don't have static sizes, which is what all this code if for filtering through.

Comment: @Robofan Have you tried stepping through the code or putting a breakpoint on the `ComboBox1.AddItem` lines to check that what's being added is indeed a string?

Comment: @Mistella Yes, I just double checked. It's a string being added. I just revised to make sure that it's always  a string that's being added.